# vaadin 14 dataProvider with fromFilteringCallbacks method issue

Tags: spring-boot, vaadin

I'm working with Vaadin 14 & Springboot application
I created a combobox and set the DataProvider using fromFilteringCallbacks function.My issue is the combobox is all time empty althougth I have data in  database and also after debugging I found out that the second part of the query (size query) it's called but the first part of it(fetch part) it's never called! does anyone face this issue before and is there a way to fix that?.here's my code :

```
UI:
ComboBox<Person> personCombo = new ComboBox<Person>();
        personCombo.setDataProvider(service.fetchPersons());
data provider:
public DataProvider<Person, String> fetchPersons() {
        return DataProvider.fromFilteringCallbacks(query -> {
            String filter = query.getFilter().orElse("");
            return service.fetchPersons(query.getOffset(), query.getLimit(), filter).stream();
        }, query -> {
            String filter = query.getFilter().orElse("");
            return (int) service.getPersonsCount(filter);
        });
    }
Service:
public Page<Person> fetchPersons(int offset, int limit, String filter) {
        Example<Person> example = createExample(filter);
        Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(offset / limit, limit);

        return getRepository().findAll(example, pageable);
    }

    public long getPersonsCount(String filter) {

        Example<Person> example = createExample(filter);
        return getRepository().count(example);
    }


        private Example<Person> createExample(String filter) {
        if (filter != null && !filter.isEmpty())
            person.setName(filter);
        ExampleMatcher exampleMatcher = ExampleMatcher.matching()
                .withMatcher("name", GenericPropertyMatcher.of(StringMatcher.CONTAINING).ignoreCase()));

        Example<Person> example = Example.of(person, exampleMatcher);
        return example;
    }
```

Comment: Just a guess: maybe the count query returns 0? In that case, there wouldn't be any reason to even try to fetch items.